# Creating sample points that cover all values of underlaying raster using R

Tags: raster, r, classification, confusion-matrix, sample

I need to create sample points to extract the values of a predicted raster. The values correspond to the predicted classes and are NOT occurring in the same number. In order to be able to create a confusion matrix, I need sample points that cover all predicted classes (or all raster values).

I know that there is tool in QGIS from the EnMapBox3 which is doing this ('Random samples from classification dataset', where we can choose how many sample per category are wanted), but I would like to do it in R.

Do the arguments 'method','weights' or 'strata' of the terra:spatSample() funtion help here?

```
s_points_valid <- spatSample(preds_mask, 300, na.rm=TRUE,xy=TRUE)
```

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with the arguments and gotten errors? What about looking at tutorials? This forum provides answers to questions that solve problems or errors. What you're asking for is more like a tutorial, which this forum is not intended for. https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/asking-good-questions-for-gis-stack-exchange

Comment: If you want exactly the same number sampled from each classification then the `method="stratified"` does that. If you want 5 from one class and 10 from the second and 8 from the third and so on, I don't think you can do it without coding a loop of some sort and sampling from a subset.

Comment: It would help if you could set up a test situation in the question with a sample raster (generated like: `r = rast(matrix(sample(1:3,20,TRUE),5,4))` or such) and a specification of how you want to sample from the 3 classes, and the output format you want - `spatSample` returns raster cell points, but do you want points in continuous space that lie somewhere in raster cells?